# How Can I Change a Label Based On a UIImageView's Current Size (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uilabel, uiviewanimation

I have a UIImageView that is scaling with an animation using the following:

```
     UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay:0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.innerCircle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.5, 3.5)
    }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.innerCircle.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        })}
```

The animation works great! **What I am confused about is how I can change a label's text based on the current size of the animated imageview.** For example, when the image is growing, it would say "Inhale," and when it is shrinking it would say "Exhale."

My first instinct as a newbie is to set up if-statements to check what the width/height of the imageview is and change the text based on that, but I can't even figure out how to reference the width.

I appreciate any guidance you can give me!